# R: paste() a certain string only if bool is TRUE (conditional strings)?

Tags: r, regex, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I have the following code:

```
run_name = paste("run", "_", gsub(" ", "_", gsub(":", "", Sys.time())), sep="")
if(ROUNDING) run_name =  paste(run_name, "_R", sep="")
```

which generates a name like `run_2021-06-29_101105` and for `ROUNDING = TRUE` it will add "_R": `run_2021-06-29_101105_R`

I'd like to include other parameters in the run_name and could do so with a line for each. But I vaguely remember (though maybe it was another programming language) that this is possible in one line with something like this `(ROUNDING|"R"|"")` :

```
run_name = paste("run", "_", gsub(" ", "_", gsub(":", "", Sys.time())), (ROUNDING|"R"|"") , sep="")
```

Is there such a thing (syntax for "conditional strings"?!) in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an object before the statement

```
 param <- ifelse(ROUNDING,"R","")
```

and then paste it in your `runame`:

```
run_name <- paste("run", "_", gsub(" ", "_", gsub(":", "", Sys.time())),
                  param,
                  sep="")
```

Comment: And so you can add other parameters for alternative extensions

Comment: thanks, the `ifelse()` was what I was looking for. that allows for the one-liner: `run_name <- paste("run", "_", gsub(" ", "_", gsub(":", "", Sys.time())), ifelse(ROUNDING,"_R",""), sep="")`. Maybe include that one line in the answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Yes, it works in one sentence too :) But be careful to indent your code correctly if you start having multiple extensions and ifelse ;)

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
param <- case_when(ROUNDING  ~"R", TRUE  ~"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use the same approach as you using `if`/`else` (since `ROUNDING` is a scalar value) rather than `ifelse` but instead of series of `paste` and `gsub` statements just use `format`.

```
run_name <- format(Sys.time(), 'run_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
if(ROUNDING)  run_name <- paste0(run_name, '_R')
```

Or if you need a one-liner -

```
run_name <- paste0(format(Sys.time(), 'run_%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S'), if(ROUNDING) '_R' else '')
```